# How do you set properties in a vcproj file with cmake?

Tags: windows, visual-studio, cmake

vcproj files for Visual Studio contain various settings or properties which affect the build. For instance, a few of the ones that a project that I'm trying to convert to cmake uses are

```
StringPooling="true"
RuntimeLibrary="2"
TreatWChar_tAsBuiltInType="true"
WarningLevel="3"
Detect64BitPortabilityProblems="false"
```

There are of course plenty of others that could be set. The question is how to set them when the project is generated using cmake. Does anyone have any idea how to set these sort of properties when using cmake other than editing the vcproj file after the fact? I can't find anything explaining how these sort of properties might be set via cmake. The only ones that I know how to set are ones that cmake specifically has cross-platform stuff for (e.g. `PreprocessorDefinitions` or `AdditionalIncludeDirectories`). But I need to be able to set ones that are specific to Visual Studio.

Comment: As far as i know all these properties transformed to corresponding command-line parameters to compiler (linker), so you can add these parameters via add_definition, or set_target_properties

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For the flags you've listed, you'd add the following to your CMakeLists.txt:

```
if(MSVC)
  # StringPooling: true == /GF  false == /GF-
  set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} /GF")

  # RuntimeLibrary
  # 0 (MultiThreaded) == /MT
  # 1 (MultiThreadedDebug) == /MTd
  # 2 (MultiThreadedDLL) == /MD
  # 3 (MultiThreadedDebugDLL) == /MDd
  set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE} /MD")
  set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG} /MDd")

  # TreatWChar_tAsBuiltInType: true == /Zc:wchar_t  false == /Zc:wchar_t-
  set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} /Zc:wchar_t")

  # WarningLevel: /W<level 0 to 4> or /Wall
  set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} /W3")

  # Detect64BitPortabilityProblems: /Wp64 - Deprecated since VC++ 2010 
  set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} /Wp64")
endif()
```

You can group these in one call if you want:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} /GF /Zc:wchar_t /W3 /Wp64")
```

If you only need to add a flag to a single target (say, `MyTestExe`), you can do:

```
set_target_properties(MyTestExe PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS "/GF- /W2")
```

Options set via this target-specific method will override any conflicting ones in the general `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` variable.

For further info on these commands do:

`cmake --help-variable "CMAKE_<LANG>_FLAGS_DEBUG"`
`cmake --help-command set_target_properties`
`cmake --help-property COMPILE_FLAGS`

The Visual Studio compiler options are listed [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fwkeyyhe.aspx).

Comment: It looks like you can also set the compiler flags via `add_definitions`.

Comment: Yeah - there's often more than one way of doing things with CMake.  The guys at Kitware are really big on maintaining backwards compatibility, so if you find a technique that works, it's likely to keep on working.  I think the `add_definitions` was originally designed to be used to set preprocessor definitions, but at some point its functionality has been extended.

Comment: @Fraser This does not seem to work for the GenerateXMLDocumentationFiles="true" or /doc flag. Just setting the flag does not generate the XML file - it appears to rely on the setting in the .vcproj file. Any tips on how to activate this using CMake?

Comment: For extra properties, use command args with `--` like, `cmake --build . --config Release -- -property:GenerateFullPaths=true -v:q`

Answer (score 1):

Each of these properties corresponds to a command-line option of the compiler (`cl`). You set these command line options in your CMakeList (using variables like `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS`, commands like `add_definitions()` and properties like `COMPILE_FLAGS`) and CMake automatically translates them to the settings in .vc[x]proj files when generating them. Those it does not understand are just added as "Additional command-line options".

Answer (score 1):

In general, you can do it like this:

```
set_target_properties(target_name
                      PROPERTIES VS_GLOBAL_CAExcludePath "....")
```

"VS_GLOBAL_ can be set to add a Visual Studio project-specific global variable. Qt integration works better if VS_GLOBAL_QtVersion is set to the Qt version FindQt4.cmake found. For example, “4.7.3”" source: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.20/prop_tgt/VS_GLOBAL_variable.html