# function (re)definition in CMake

Tags: c++, cmake

I want to use a #define statement to redirect a number of Windows functions for easy compilation of existing code on Linux. (The matching of the functionality of the different functions doesn't have to be perfect for now, it just has to compile.)

An example would be:

```
#define sprintf_s(a, b, c, d) snprintf(a, b, c, d)
```

Now I don't want to do this in every file where the functions occur and I do already have a CMake environment. Is there any way to use a `add_definitions()` statement or something similar to do this globally for the whole project?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/d-preprocessor-definitions and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14148374/how-do-you-set-properties-in-a-vcproj-file-with-cmake

Comment: Ah sorry, I mistyped. I meant compilation on Linux, not on Windows.

Comment: Well, `-D` works in gcc too.

Comment: The linked pages unfortunately only tell me that can do something like add_definitions(-DFLAG=1).
What I am trying to do, is something like add_definitions(-Dsprintf_s(a, b, c, d)=snprintf(a, b, c, d)), which doesn't work that way. Do you have  any Idea how to do that?

Comment: Put all your macro redefinitions in a file and do a forced include into all sources with `/FI"redefinitions.h"` for MSVC compilers or `-include "redefinitions.h"` for GCC compiler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a header file containing your redefinitions, then surround it with a guard which is enabled and passed through by your CMake configuration:

In your "redefinitions.h":

```
#ifndef REDEFINITIONS_H
#define REDEFINITIONS_H

#ifdef REDEF
#define sprintf_s(a, b, c, d) snprintf(a, b, c, d)
/* #define ... */
/* #define ... */
/* #define ... */
#endif

#endif /* REDEFINITIONS_H */
```

Then in your `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
# Optional CMake Option
# Use with: cmake -DREDEFINITIONS=OFF
option(REDEFINITIONS "Cross-platform symbol redefinitions" ON)
if(REDEFINITIONS)
    add_definitions(-DREDEF)
endif()

# Or optional platform detection
if(UNIX AND NOT APPLE) 
    add_definitions(-DREDEF)
endif()
```

or for specific targets instead,

```
target_compile_definitions(mytarget PUBLIC REDEF=1)
```

Comment: Excuse me if I overlook the obvious here but do I have to #include redefinitions.h in every file where I need those redefinitions? Because editing every file is what I wanted to avoid.

Comment: @EXIT_FAILURE You can add a forced include to avoid manual editing. But this is the basic approach that is used by most and applies to both methods.

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to utopia I was able to solve my problem like this:

I created a new file called "redefinitions.h"  in a folder called "redefinitions", containing only the required function redefinitions, e.g.:

```
redefinitions.h:

#define sprintf_s(a, b, c, d) snprintf(a, b, c, d)
[...]
```

Then I added the following lines to my CMake file:

```
CMakeLists:

[...]

option(REDEFINITIONS "Cross-platform symbol redefinitions" ON)
if(REDEFINITIONS)
    include_directories(redefinitions)
    add_compile_options(-include redefinitions.h)
endif()

[...]
```

This may not be the most elegant solution but I works and requires minimal effort.